# Use sed to modify xml file

Tags: xml, sed

I need to search an xml file for some text that resides within a start/end tag and if found, to write a line of text just before the end tag.

Eg, in the **XML file** I need to search **MyTag** for "MyText1". If found, add **FoundIt** right before the end tag as shown below

```
 <MyTag>
 <Tag1>MyText1</Tag1>
 <Tag2>MyText2</Tag2>
 <Tag3>MyText3</Tag3>
 <Tag4>MyText4</Tag4>
 <FoundTag1>FoundIt</FoundTag1>
 </MyTag>
```

I was able to use sed to search for the range and print MyText1. But what I really want to be able to do is add the "FoundIt" tag right before the end tag.

**Sed Script**

```
/<MyTag>/,/<\/MyTag>/{
/<Tag1>MyText1</Tag1>/p
}
```

**XML File Contents**

```
<XmlFile>

<BeginTag>
<SomeTag>Text</SomeTag>
</BegingTag>

<MyTag>
<Tag1>MyText1</Tag1>
<Tag2>MyText2</Tag2>
<Tag3>MyText3</Tag3>
<Tag4>MyText4</Tag4>
</MyTag>

<EndTag>
<SomeTag>Text</SomeTag>
</EndTag>

</XmlFile>
```

Comment: Your question alone provided the answer I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<MyTag>/!b;:a;/<\/MyTag>/!{$!{N;ba}};/MyText1/s/.*\n/&<FoundTag1>FoundIt<\/FoundTag1>\n/' xml_file
```

Look for a line containing `<MyTag>` if not bail out. Once found, collect lines until the line `</MyTag>` occurs, then check if those lines contain `MyText1` and if so substitute  `<FoundTag1>FoundIt</FoundTag1>` followed by a new line before the last line collected.

Comment: Is there a way to match "^<MyTag>$" instead of "<MyTag>" ? When I used ^ and $ it stopped working as expected.

Comment: @TeaBee try `/^\s*<MyTag>\s*$/` this caters for white space either side of the tag'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sed -n '
    /<MyTag>/,/<\/MyTag>/!{p;}; 
    /<MyTag>/,/<\/MyTag>/{H;}; 
    /<\/MyTag>/{s/.*//;x;}; 
    /.*MyText1.*/{s/<\/MyTag>/<FoundTag1>FoundIt<\/FoundTag1>\n&/;};
    /<\/MyTag>/{p;}; 
' \
xml_file
```

Comment: That would be too easy. I cannot do that because I can only add FoundIt, it MyText1 is in the MyTag element. Your sed command does not check whether MyText1 exists in the MyTag element.